# selecting records that have a many to many relationship using active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails app that has the following models.  The empgroup is for a many-to-many relationship between workgroup and employee.

employee.rb

```
  has_many :empgroups
  has_many :workgroups, through: :empgroups
```

empgroup.rb

```
  belongs_to :employee
  belongs_to :workgroup
```

workgroup.rb

```
  has_many :empgroups
  has_many :employees, through: :empgroups
  has_many :workorders
```

I would like an index list of workorders assigned to workgroups that an employee belongs to.

I was hoping this would work, but it didn't:

```
current_user.employee.workgroups.workorders.each do
```

It gave me:

```
undefined method `workorders'
```

So, I'm trying a `joins`, but it doesn't work either:

```
Workorders.joins(:workgroups => :employees).where(employee_id = current_user.employee).each do
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to collect the workgroups and iterate through all workorders:

```
current_user.employee.workgroups.each |group| do
  group.workorders.each do
    ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** - ugh, what was I thinking.

Like this:

```
@employee_workorders = Workorder.joins(workgroups: employees).where(employees: { id: current_user.employee })
```

---

```
current_user.employee.workgroups.map(&:workorders).flatten.uniq
```

should give you an array of the workorders.